# Find an example of a discontinuous positive semi-definite real function

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone give an example of a discontinuous, positive semi-definite real function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

It is a well known fact that $f(t)= e^{-|t|}$ is a positive semi-definite real function. So perhaps the discontinuous function $g(t) = f(t)$ on $t\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ and $g(0)=2$ is also positive semi-definite, however I haven't been able to show it.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I don't think so. The statement of Bochner's theorem refers to continuous positive semi-definite functions. That hypothesis wouldn't be needed if they were all continuous. I think what you're referring to is that any positive semi-definite function that arises from Bochner's theorem (for example, a characteristic function in probability theory) is necessarily uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is right. From the definition of  positive semi-definite function it is quite easy to see that if $f$ is positive semi-definite and $g(x)=f(x)$ for $ x \neq 0$ and $g(0)>f(0)$ then $g$ is also positive semi-definite: $ \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n} c_j\overline {c_k} g(t_i-t_j)=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n} c_j\overline {c_k} f(t_i-t_j)+ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} |c_j|^{2} (g(0)-f(0))$.

Comment: You have to deal with the possibility that $t_i=t_j$ but $i\neq j$, and it's not so trivial because some of those $c_i \overline{c}_j$ terms can be negative.